# How does CFNetwork use the BSD Socket, and how does NSUrl use the CFNetwork?

Tags: ios, sockets, nsurl, cfnetwork

There is some doc that explain how does CFNetwork use the BSD Socket and how does NSUrl use the CFNetwork?

I'm interested in it for didactical purpose, but on the official [doc](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Networking/Conceptual/CFNetwork/Concepts/Concepts.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001132-CH4-SW10), about CFNetwork, i can read only

> Just as CFNetwork relies on BSD sockets, there are a number of Cocoa classes that rely on CFNetwork (NSURL, for example).